# how to create and terminate a EMR cluster using single lambda using cloud watch events

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr

i'm pretty new to this and i would like to create a emr cluster at 0900 everyday and terminate it again at 1300 using cloudwatch event triggers. I wanted this to happen through a single lambda(python) instead of creating 2 lambdas one for creating and one for terminating.
please help me out

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-east-1')

response = client.run_job_flow(
    Name="Boto3 test cluster",
    ReleaseLabel='emr-5.12.0',
    Instances={
        'MasterInstanceType': 'm4.xlarge',
        'SlaveInstanceType': 'm4.xlarge',
        'InstanceCount': 3,
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
        'TerminationProtected': False,
        'Ec2SubnetId': 'my-subnet-id',
        'Ec2KeyName': 'my-key',
    },
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole'
)
```

what do i have to add this code to make it suit my requirements ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your 2 lambda code

Comment: emr_client = boto3.client('emr') emr_client.terminate_job_flows(JobFlowIds=["my cluster id" ]) . I'm going to use this  to terminate the cluster

Comment: why don't you EDIT your question

Comment: I don't see any lambda in your code, and where do you mention `0900` and `1300`

Comment: yeah mate changed my question. And i am trying to invoke this lambda through cloud watch events at 9 and 1300. I hope I'm clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to create 2 different Cloudwatch event and them at schedule 0900 and 1300 respectively ( using cron expression). Set them to trigger you lambda.

Modify you lambda code to process the event information and get the "resources" which will have your scheduled rule name.

Now base on that value run your code.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-east-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
 
rule_name = event["Records"][0]["resources"].split("/")[-1]

if rule_name == 'crete_emr_rule':
  response = client.run_job_flow(
    Name="Boto3 test cluster",
    ReleaseLabel='emr-5.12.0',
    Instances={
        'MasterInstanceType': 'm4.xlarge',
        'SlaveInstanceType': 'm4.xlarge',
        'InstanceCount': 3,
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
        'TerminationProtected': False,
        'Ec2SubnetId': 'my-subnet-id',
        'Ec2KeyName': 'my-key',
    },
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole'
   )
elif rule_name = "Terminate emr rule":
  list_emr = client.list_clusters(
  CreatedAfter=datetime(2021, 1, 1)# use time/date function to get these values
  CreatedBefore=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
  ClusterStates=['WAITING'],
  )   

  cluster_id = list_emr['Clusters'][0][Id]
  client.terminate_job_flows(JobFlowIds=[cluster_id])
```

Comment: fix the indentation, seems to be important for python